# fputcsv - only one column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, csv, fputcsv

I want to save parts (and differently arranged) of my mysql database in a CSV file. For that I  wrote this piece of code:

```
$headerDisplayed = false;
foreach ($arr as &$currName)
{
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Experiment Where Person='$currName'"); 
    $i = 1;
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) 
    {
        $list['Name'] = $currName;
        $list['Studie'] = $row2['Studie']; 
        if(strcmp($row2['Antwort'],$row2['Korrekt']) == 0)
        {
            $list["A $i"] = '0';
        }
        else
        {
            $list["A $i"] = '1';
        }

        $i++;
    }

    if ( !$headerDisplayed ) {
        // Use the keys from $data as the titles
        fputcsv($fp, array_keys($list));
        $headerDisplayed = true;
    }

    fputcsv($fp, $list);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Unfortunately this does not what I wanted it to do. My plan was that each entry of `$list` (e.g. `$list["A 1"]` or `$list["A 15"]`) has its own column. And then the call of `fputcsv` should create a new line and again one column for each `$list` entry.
I create new rows with each `fputcsv` call, just as expected, but the complete `$list` array is in the first (most left) column.

What do I have to do to solve this issue?

**ADDED:**
I get something like:

```
[1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0] [] [] [] [] [] [] []

[1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0] [] [] [] [] [] [] []

[0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1] [] [] [] [] [] [] []
```

but what I want is more like:

```
[1] [0] [0] [0] [1] [1] [0] [0]

[1] [0] [1] [1] [0] [1] [0] [0]

[0] [1] [1] [1] [1] [1] [0] [1]
```

Comment: So, where do you get this "result" gets displayed this way? Excel?

Comment: Ok, then this is your problem. Use the 3rd and 4th parameter of fputcsv() to get your CSV format fit to excel. (Dont know what excel  accepts immediately)

Comment: That helped so much, thank you. All I had do do was changing to "fputcsv($fp, $list, ';',' ');"  ... Is it possible to give you a +1 for this comment? Or which one do I mark as answer?

Comment: I made the change to my answer below...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This this:

```
fputcsv($fp, array_values($list));
```

EDIT:

Use this to get it instantly working with excel:

```
fputcsv($fp, array_values($list), ';', ' ');
```

EDIT 2:
The default character that is used as the field-separator in excel is set by the locale settings of windows. That means: If you export a csv-file with german locale settings will cause problems with excel in an us-environment... Another [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/180964/how-to-open-semicolon-delimited-csv-files-in-us-version-of-excel) covered this topic.

Comment: I can run it, and it returns a CSV file which has "This is a test,"""This"" is a test","This is a 'test'","This is a" in its first row first column and then "test" in next row. And this repeated a lot of times.

Comment: Cool! change delimiter to ";" works perfect! Thank you very much! Still I am curious why using "," as the delimiter doesn't work???

Comment: Why is there a ' ' space for enclosure ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
fputs($fp, implode(array_keys($list), ',')."\n");

fputs($fp, implode(array_values($list), ',')."\n");
```

Comment: Bad idea! What, if the input is somethink like: "Surname, Firstname" ?

Comment: That would not be the case, even $list['Name'] is in fact not a name but a coded integer number referring to a name. But still this doesn't change anything. I add something to my question.

Comment: Your code just handles the header-column. If you apply this on the csv-content, a comma in a field could possibly occure...

Comment: @Justin Why whould one use array_map together with fputcsv just wo wrap "" aroung fields? Just use fputcsv($f, $array, ';', '"');

Comment: I tested it anyway. It messes everything completely up^^  But thank you very much for your trys and your efford :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a matrix:

```
        {
            $list["A"]["$i"] = '0';
        }
        else
        {
            $list["A"]["$i"] = '1';
        }
```

See example 1 of http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: This only leads to [Array] in each row of the csv file :(